# C semaphore from Python

Tags: python, c, ipc, semaphore

I have a C code in which I have implemented a locking mechanism using semaphore. The basic flow is as below -

```
int s=1;
void wait(){

    while(s<=0);
    s--;
}

void pipeData(paTestData *data){

    wait();

    SAMPLE *tempBuff = (SAMPLE*)malloc(sizeof(SAMPLE)*FRAME_SIZE);
    int readCount   = FRAME_SIZE;

    while(readCount > 0){

        tempBuff[FRAME_SIZE - readCount] = data->sampleValues[data->readFromCB];        
        data->readFromCB++;
        readCount--;
    }

    fd = open(fifoPipe, O_WRONLY);

    write(fd, tempBuff, sizeof(tempBuff));
    close(fd);

    free(tempBuff);

}

int callBack(){

    // Perform data acquisition and call foo

   foo();

    // Rest code here
}
```

The python code at the reader end is as below:

```
with open(FIFO, 'rb') as fifo:
                print("Pipe opened")
                count=0
                while count<framelen:
                    Rsample = fifo.read()
                    frame = np.fromstring(Rsample,dtype=np.float32)

                    if (len(frame)>0):
                        print(frame)
                        count=count + len(frame)
```

The data on the other end of the `PIPE` is being processed by a Python Script. The problem is that the reading of the PIPE on python end is not able to fetch the full set of the data.

It's because I had read that for `named PIPE` for every write, there should a reader or else the pipe open is blocked during next iteration.

In this case, after writing `10 samples` to the PIPE, the python's reader implementation is able to `read only first two samples` and the PIPE is readily available for next write set.

This is the reason why I was looking for a `locking mechanism` for the same.

My doubts are -

> 1) Is there a way in which I could increment the s variable (kind of
>   what a signal() function in C would do) every time the python script
>   is finished polling up all data from PIPE.
>
> 2) Is there any other smooth implementation of such a problem, any
>   other IPC technique between C and Python enabling lock mechanism?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to explain your *actual* problem a bit better. What's the condition you're waiting for? There's no problem just writing to a pipe, it will block as soon as the pipe buffer is full. Apart from that, your implementation of the semaphore isn't atomic, so it's more or less useless with concurrency.

Comment: A simple solution for synchronizing processes is using more pipes, where a *signal* is writing a single character to that pipe (while the other end is in a blocking read)

Comment: I don't see any pipe code.  You say you are "polling", so are you using a non-blocking pipe?  Have you looked at the new-ish asyncio module?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore

Comment: @FelixPalmen I think using another `PIPE` would solve the purpose. Will let you know after implementing it. Thanks!

Comment: @AshishK regarding your edit, it looks more like your problem might be some buffering. Pipes have buffers themselves, but a read should always be able to get all the data waiting in the pipe. Maybe you should show the python code reading from the pipe, so some python expert could tell you where it's going wrong. (also show the actual pipe writing code in C)

Comment: @cdarke , I know very basics of Python as of now, I may be asking something silly but wanted to know how does this `acquire` and `release` function would know about the `s` variable that I have used in my `C` file.

Comment: @AshishK this looks like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) now. You had some problems reading all the data from a pipe you wrote there, and your idea was you could solve this with locking. Now you ask about locking. I don't think that's the solution.

Comment: Semaphores, and many other such inter-thread signaling, cannot sensibly be implemented outside the OS kenel because threads cannot be blocked in user space.  That, and the XY issue mentioned by the other commenters.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, I have tried editing the solution with the details you asked for. Please have a look

Comment: I just thought to ask suggestions on the approach I was taking and I am not rigid on this approach. Please don't take it as an `XY` problem as `I have mentioned my doubt in details, given one way in which I approached it and now open to any kind of suggestions I get.`

Answer (score 2):

```
write(fd, tempBuff, sizeof(tempBuff));
```

The above line only write 4/8 bytes (32-bit/64-bit) of data from tempBuff to pipe

If you want to write all data within tempBuff, you need to change the line to

```
write(fd, tempBuff, sizeof(SAMPLE)*FRAME_SIZE);
```

Comment: thankyou, however is there any way in which I can use `signal()` type of function from python to increment the `s` variable in C ? I mean is it even possible?
This has actually solved my problem but through this implementation I wanted to learn about handling C semaphores from Python Script. Thanks!

Comment: @AshishK what you have in your C code is not a usable semaphore, so better forget about this now.

Comment: @FelixPalmen ok. Thank you so much for your time, I appreciate :)